# Thai X Terminal installed in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

[image: thai x terminal]

I have noticed this thing today. Before that, I use to open a terminal by `Ctrl+Alt+A`.

I installed "Termius" and to open the "Termius", I searched the term & got this.

Does anybody know why this got installed or where did it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came from the [`xiterm+thai`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xiterm%2Bthai) package.

Its desktop file is located in */usr/share/applications/xiterm+thai.desktop* and [contains its name](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/xiterm+thai/wily/view/head:/debian/xiterm%2Bthai.desktop#L3):

> ```
> Name=Thai X terminal
> Comment=X Terminal that supports Thai (TIS-620 encoding)
> ```

Technically it is one of the `x-terminal-emulator` [alternatives](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/xiterm+thai/wily/view/head:/debian/control#L21).

See [bug 1747341](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lubuntu-next/+bug/1747341) about its unexpected installation.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to N0rbert's answer:

You can get rid of this package via

```
sudo apt-get purge xiterm+thai
```